# Space concatenated with an expression is sometimes dropped

Tags: javascript

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4yhkquy/) contains:

```
var d = " " + true ? "am" : "pm";
var e = " " + "am";
alert("|" + d + "|");
alert("|" + e + "|");
```

Why does `d` not contain the leading space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do same like 
`var d = (" " +  true) ? "am" : "pm"`
In your case the condition is `" " +  true`.
Correct condition is `var d = (true ? "am" : "pm")`

```
var d = " " + true ? "am" : "pm";   //output    |am|
var d = (" " + true) ? "am" : "pm";   //output  |am|
var d = " " + (true ? "am" : "pm");   //output  | am|
```

Answer (score 2):

you want `var d = " " + (true ? "am" : "pm")`

Answer (score 1):

[Check the edit here.](https://jsfiddle.net/13e4oLq7/)

The javascript order of operations is computing `" " + true` before the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

" " + true evaluates to boolean.. you need

```
var d = " " + (true ? "am" : "pm");
```